# Juniper MX: Leaking routes from RIB into VRF

Tags: juniper, juniper-mx, vrf

### Aim

We have a firewall terminating IPSec VPNs to AWS. These are used in the event of  failure of a pair of AWS Direct Connects. Currently, the VPNs are routed to AWS over the same Direct Connects that they are backing up - if the Direct Connects stop routing traffic for some reason, the VPNs break also.

### Proposed Solution

Create a VRF on Juniper MX into which we import AWS routes learned from Transit and not those learned from the Direct Connects.

### Implementation

```
phil@mx# show routing-instances
be-fw-tunnels {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ae0.336;
    routing-options {
        instance-import vrf_be_fw_tunnels;
    }
}

phil@mx# show policy-options policy-statement vrf_be_fw_tunnels
term no_aws_direct {
    from {
        instance master;
        community Direct;
    }
    then reject;
}
term aws_indirect {
    from {
        instance master;
        as-path aws-indirect;
    }
    then accept;
}
term no_more {
    then reject;
}

phil@mx# show policy-options as-path aws-indirect
".* (14618|16509)$";
```

### Problem

The solution works to the extent that *some* Amazon routes are leaked into the VRF however only for prefixes which are not advertised by Amazon on the Direct Connect at all. This is, I presume, because `instance-import` imports from the FIB and the routes of interest installed in the FIB are all from the Direct Connect peering.

### Question

Is it possible to import into a VRF from the RIB, such that all possible routes are considered for import... not just the currently active ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution seems to be to use `rib-group`. I always assumed `rib-group` and `instance-import` were interchangeable though, as the name suggests, `rib-group` works in the RIB whereas `instance-import` only works on the FIB.

Syntax is significantly more complex but it's nice in such that you can apply `rib-group` to individual BGP peers which avoids the need to explicitly filter out the routes you don't want.

```
phil@mx# show routing-instances
be-fw-tunnels {
    description "VRF importing specific DFZ routes for use by BE FW tunnels";
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ae0.236;
}

phil@mx# show routing-options rib-groups
/* Export some IPv4 routes from the main table into the be-fw-tunnels table */
be-fw-tunnels-v4 {
    import-rib [ inet.0 be-fw-tunnels.inet.0 ];
    import-policy vrf_be_fw_tunnels;
}
/* Export some IPv6 routes from the main table into the be-fw-tunnels table */
be-fw-tunnels-v6 {
    import-rib [ inet6.0 be-fw-tunnels.inet6.0 ];
    import-policy vrf_be_fw_tunnels;
}

phil@mx# show policy-options policy-statement vrf_be_fw_tunnels
term aws_indirect {
    from as-path aws-indirect;
    then accept;
}
term no_more {
    then reject;
}

phil@mx# show groups
/* Apply to BGP groups from which you want to export certain routes to the be-fw-tunnels VRF */
aws-to-vrf-v4 {
    protocols {
        bgp {
            group <*> {
                neighbor "<[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*>" {
                    family inet {
                        unicast {
                            rib-group be-fw-tunnels-v4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
/* Apply to BGP groups from which you want to export certain routes to the be-fw-tunnels VRF */
aws-to-vrf-v6 {
    protocols {
        bgp {
            group <*> {
                neighbor <*:*:*> {
                    family inet6 {
                        unicast {
                            rib-group be-fw-tunnels-v6;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

phil@mx# show protocols bgp group Transit
apply-groups [ aws-to-vrf-v4 aws-to-vrf-v6 ];
...
```